# Why is 589587 off topic? (Windows 7 64 RAM Drive)

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The following question:

https://superuser.com/questions/76757/ram-drive-for-vista-win7-64bit/589587

> I'm looking for a (hopefully free) RAM drive utility for Windows 7 64
>   (one for Vista 64 would also likely work). I use an SSD for my OS/App
>   drive, and I'd like to minimize temp file access on it by putting my
>   temporary folder on a RAM drive. I have an abundance of RAM, and
>   reserving half a GB for a RAM drive would be useful.
>
> AR RAM disk is discontinued, and does not support Windows 7 64bit.
>
> Any recommendations?

is, I feel a popular and useful one. At the time, 64bit compatible RAM utilities were rare, and even now not all support 64 bit. There are other questions not closed that also ask for information about software to meet specific criteria, such as this question about syncing a RAM drive to HD:

- [Looking for Windows RAM Disk which mirrors writes to hard disk](https://superuser.com/questions/248419/looking-for-windows-ram-disk-which-mirrors-writes-to-hard-disk)

or this question about a RAM Drive for Ubuntu:

- [Ramdisk ubuntu 10.04](https://superuser.com/questions/175861/ramdisk-ubuntu-10-04)

I don't mind an off-topic question being closed, I just am not sure what makes this particular question off topic?  It appears that obscure utility software are within the scope of the FAQ.

Comment: I don't see how this question falls under the mentioned off-topic category (you are clearly looking for *any* utility, not for the "best shopping choice"), but I've noticed a raising amount of folks here on SE who tend to delete, erase and eliminate without much consideration.

Answer (score 6):

It's a shopping question.  Those are off-topic per [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: Fair 'nuff. Thanks.

Comment: Not constructive would have also fit.

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning, the OP could have found an acceptable answer [here: Why would a RAMdisk be used today?](http://superuser.com/questions/34433/why-would-a-ramdisk-be-used-today) (personally, I would have considered the post in question a duplicate thereof).

Answer (score 1):

The question is off-topic as a product recommendation question.  See the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq#questions) for details.  For the rationale behind this, see this Stack Exchange Blog post: [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: In the linked article, there's a clear example where a person asks for a hint on a camera choice. So product recommendations are off-topic when they depend on unknown variable factors (price, location, etc) that might be important. Here the OP clearly asks for /any/ recommendation, so personally I don't see any evil in that.